# Show a different display value based on if the column is null or not

Tags: sql

In this query I want to be able to have- for the column attached_document, if there is a null value, I want to have it output 'No attachment' else for any value there, it would be 'has attachment'.

```
select ev.actual_date, ev.event_name, ev.generic_description, ev.full_name as client_name, 
ev.staff_desc as staff, ev.user_entered_desc as entered_by, ev.attached_document
from event_view ev where event_name in
('Treatment Plan', 'Treatment Plan Rev.2', 'Treatment Plan Review',
'Treatment Plan Review Rev.2') and is_service_event = '1' 
order by event_name, actual_date, client_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT
   ev.actual_date
   ,ev.event_name
   ,ev.generic_description
   ,ev.full_name         AS client_name
   ,ev.staff_desc        AS staff
   ,ev.user_entered_desc AS entered_by
   ,COALESCE(ev.attached_document,'No attachment') AS  attached_document
FROM
   event_view ev
WHERE
   event_name IN
   (
       'Treatment Plan'
       ,'Treatment Plan Rev.2'
       ,'Treatment Plan Review'
       ,'Treatment Plan Review Rev.2'
   )
   AND is_service_event = '1'
ORDER BY
   event_name
   ,actual_date
   ,client_name;
```

Comment: HI Mehdi, thank you for the response and editing. When I run it does not produce any results.

Comment: Please try without where clause and check if any result was returned.